# Why should one subclass instead of composite when using the Factory Method design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, inheritance, composition, factory-method

I'm currently learning about design patterns. I learned about the Factory Method pattern.

This pattern means that in order to implement a factory to create objects, one should subclass the class that needs these objects, and have the subclass create them. This way the superclass only works with more abstract references instead of the concrete implementations the subclass generates, which creates a loosely coupled design.

This usually means the superclass becomes `abstract`, since it's `createObject()` method must be `abstract` so that the subclass containing the factory method will have to implement this method.

Like any factory pattern, this pattern encapsulates the creation of the concrete object, and allows the client to work with a higher level of abstraction. But this specific pattern is built on inheritance.

**What I don't understand is** - Why would anybody go through all the trouble of subclassing the class that needs a factory and making it `abstract`? **Composition is so much better for this purpose in any way.**

It makes much more sense to **create an abstract class or an interface called `Factory`.** It would declare one method: `createObject()`. We **create concrete implementations of it for different purposes** (`WeaponFactory`, `TitleFactory`..) Then, we **give the client a `Factory` member instance `factory`.** This reference is **set to whatever concrete `Factory` is needed at runtime**, and the client can simply use `factory`'s `createObject()` when needed (without having to know what concrete implementation `factory` is holding).

I don't understand why one would go through the trouble of subclassing a class and making it abstract just for the benefit of allowing it to use a factory in a loosely-coupled manner.

The simple composition-based design I described is better in any way - I think.

**Do you agree? Could  you explain why anybody would use the Factory Method Pattern I described?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Design Patterns](http://amzn.to/XBYukB) book is *descriptive*, not *prescriptive*; it describes the patterns the GoF have observed in the wild; patterns that solve problems.

Some problems can be solved in more than one way.

The alternative you describe is also my preferred approach, but it's also described in the book: it's a combination of the **Abstract Factory** and **Strategy** patterns. You use an Abstract Factory as a Strategy.

> I don't understand why one would go through the trouble of subclassing a class and making it abstract just for the benefit of allowing it to use a factory in a loosely-coupled manner.

For the exact same reason that you would combine Abstract Factory and Strategy. However, the *best* solution partly depends on your language.

If, for example, you were programming in Eiffel, Factory Method would probably be easier, because Eiffel has multiple inheritance, but (IIRC) no interfaces.

Also, if you're using a language where you can create a derived value on the spot (such as Java or F#), Factory Method might actually be easier than the Abstract Factory/Strategy combo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You posted this a while ago but I got a question regarding this: I understand the factory patterns well as a whole, but I always have trouble drawing the line between Factory Method and Abstract Factory. In both patterns, there's an abstract superclass, and a number of concrete subclasses. The only difference I see between the two patterns (and I've tried for long to find another difference), is that Abstract Factory is always said to "produce a *family of objects*", while Factory Method usually produces one object. (Continuing in the next comment)

Comment: The only additional difference I can think of is the fact that the abstract superclass in Factory Method, usually does some manipulation on the object it recieves from it's subclass, before returning it to the client. While the abstract superclass in Abstract Factory, usually isn't said to do this. Is this actually the difference? Can you explain the difference to me? I'm having a hard time understanding (been reading a lot on this site and the web, didn't help). Thanks

Comment: OR: One additional option for the difference, may be this: In Factory Method, the client **itself** is subclassed, to get the object from it's subclass. While in Abstract Factory, the superclass-subclasses system is **extenal** to the client, and composed with it. Does this mean that if I create a Factory Method system (an abstract superclass and a number of subclasses), and give a reference to it to the client, instead of subclassing the client itself - it becomes an Abstract Factory instead of a Factory Method? A little confused here.. Would appreciate your help :)

Comment: That last comment of yours is zeroing in on the differences. Factory Methods usually exist only for the benefit of the base class. It's a way to apply the Open/Closed Principle by enabling clients to extend *that particular* class by overriding its Factory Method(s). Abstract Factory, on the other hand, only has a single responsibility: it creates objects. If composed with client classes, it can be reused across *many different* classes. Note also that Abstract Factory doesn't rely on inheritance. It can implement a factory *interface* instead of deriving from a base class.

Comment: Please let me see if I understand the differences: Let's say there is a class that needs an object. This class is called the `Client`. We have two ways to achieve this: to use Factory Method or to use Abstract Factory. I'll describe both and their difference. Using Factory Method, we create a method inside Client `createObject()`, and subclass Client. The subclass will override `createObject()`. Client would call `createObject()` when it needs to make an object, and the subclass will give it the object that answers to some general interface, without the Client knowing the concrete type (...)

Comment: In Abstract Factory, however, we don't subclass `Client`. Instead, we create an abstract superclass (or interface), and we subclass that class with different concrete classes. The abstract superclass defines a supertype of object the concrete classes should create, and the concrete classes create concrete objects of that general supertype. This system is extenal to `Client`, and then composed with it. `Client` uses this system to get objects. (...)

Comment: What all of this means, is this: As we said, the class that needs objects is called `Client`.  **In Factory Method**, we **subclass the Client itself**, giving the subclasses the responsibility to create objects. While **in Abstract Factory**, the superclass-subclass system is **external** to the `Client`, and composed with the Client so the Client may use this system - **as opposed to subclassing the `Client` itself**.

Comment: Sorry for the long comments. Is the difference I described in the last comment correct?

Comment: Yes, and you've also just described the difference between inheritance and composition. As the *Design Patterns* book state, we should favour composition over inheritance. In this case, composition is superior to inheritance because the Abstract Factory is *reusable* between multiple clients, whereas the Factory Method is coupled to the client.

Comment: If so, than this means that there is no way to use Abstract Factory without using Strategy. We always need to connect the Abstract Factory system to an object, and Strategy is the only way to do this. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's how I always use it, at least, so that sounds just about right :)

Comment: I see. Two last questions about this (I hope ;) ). 1- People often say Abstract Factory involves creating a 'family of related objects', while Factory Method gives you one object. But that's not actually the main difference between the two, and doesn't have to be a difference at all. A Factory Method subclass can implement several methods to return different objects, like Abstract Factory subclasses do. Am I right? 2- The definition from before means that a Factory Method design can be made an Abstract Factory simply by composing it with another `Client` class ..

Comment: .. since the only difference is that in Factory Method, the object-creation mechanism is coupled to the client in inheritance, and in Abstract Factory the **mechanism is the same**, but connected through composition. Is this correct?

Comment: On the conceptual level, there's not much difference. The mechanisms are language-dependent, so I don't think it makes sense to discuss them in general terms.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're looking at the problem the wrong way. If you have a need to create one of several subclasses, then you'll need to use the Factory method as you've described it to solve the problem.

For example, if you have a system where you need to have the vast majority of your code be the same but only vary in a few details, then subclassing makes sense in its own right and you'll do that, then create the factories that are able to kick out the correct subclasses based on the rules each needs. You might also have a legacy system where subclasses are already in use, and you find that as it scales you want to add factories to help with creation of your objects.

If you are using something like an Entity system and you don't need subclasses of your Product object, by all means don't create them. However, you might want to make sure your single Class at least implements an Interface, because every once in a while you need to use a completely unrelated implementation when you get a requirement you didn't see coming.

Answer (score 0):

In general i agree that composition its better than inheritance. GOF design patterns are great because there are probably the first attempt to build a language (the patterns are a language for me) in a new level of abstraction, at design level instead of programatic level, this is great, but some concrete patterns are perhaps obsolete or can be improved to adapt to your concrete situation, technology or preferences. The study of patterns is a good thing, can teach you some good OO tricks and techniques, but the application of patterns "by the book" its never a good idea IMMO.

Anyway, i see a problem with your design, at least a problem in a static typed language, WeaponFactory return weapons and titleFactory return titles i suppose, the return type for "createObject" its different and this return type is part of the signature of the method. But off course with composition and DI you can achieve the same goals that the factory method try to achieve. For example:

```
Client clientWithRealWeapon = new Client(new RealWeaponsFactory());
Client clientWithMocksWeapon = new Client(new MockWeaponsFactory());
```

its a solution with composition and DI, the same can be done creating two subclass of client: ClientWithRealWeapons and ClientWithMocksWeapons that override a method for creating weapons.